# Web app deployment using NodeJs and Express

Tags: node.js, backend, web-deployment, devops, progressive-web-apps

My question is more of a query as to how people deploy production web apps now / best methods etc.

Currently, we are looking to put into production a web app with a NodeJS backend using express as well as a frontend we have made.

Does it make sense to split the frontend and backend onto their own separate server, or to render the HTML files directly from the NodeJS backend on one server?

If you have any other suggestions please list the pros/cons and how a dev team of multiple people can easily manage the source code as there are separate people split up to just frontend and just backend.

Note: This is the actual web app, not a static site or landing page

Answer (score 0):

I went through this decision process recently, and I chose to deploy static and dynamic parts of my system **together**.

How to decide this question?

Are your front- and back- ends tied closely together? Do many front-end changes require corresponding back-end changes?  If so, that's a reason to deploy both in a single server. That was my situation.

Does it make any sense to serve your static HTML / Javascript / CSS / image resources using express's static-object server functionality?  It might: Express lets you do good things like `.js` minification, on-the-fly translation of `.less` or `.sass` files, and so forth.  It also has good facilities for handling CORS, rate-limiting, and other infosec features.  If you want those things, that's a reason to deploy both in a single server. That, too, was my situation.

Will you rig up a reverse proxy (nginx) server facing the network? That's a tricky enough configuration task that you probably want to do it once rather than twice. That's a reason to deploy both in a single server. My situation.

Do you have many many static objects to serve?  That's a reason to deploy the static objects and the web app separately: Pure apache or nginx is more suitable for serving static stuff than node. I only had a few static objects.

Is there a chance, in your devops, that two separate deployments will make things more complex and less reliable? (Will somebody forget to deploy both static and dynamic?) That's a reason to deploy both in a single server.  I did that because I want test, staging, and production deployments to work identically.

Git and other source-control systems are robust enough to allow teams to contribute to a single repo without stomping each others' work.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and the well written answer! Did you handle serving static files in node by using a middleware to keep the route names without file extensions, or did you just leave the file extensions on? Thanks!

Comment: I kept the extensions; my static objects are mostly .png, .css. .js, and other such files. Removing those extensions would make my html that much harder to understand for the next person to work on it.

Comment: Should have specified. I meant if you had any .html files you served statically